# How to design GUIs on Linux and C++

Tags: c++, linux, ide

I am new to Linux. I would like to be able to program on Linux too besides Windows and Arduino. I am running Linux mint 14 Cinnamon (Nadia) version.

I would like to make applications with a user interface. And if that would require me to use a different version then that's okay: then I would reinstall Mint KDE or XFce, that's no problem.

I've been looking at several programming tools to write C++ on Linux
So far none of them (CodeBlocks Geany and I even tried Vim) had something, to create a user interface and put your code behind it.

What I miss from Visual Studio is to be able to make a form, put buttons on it, put a text input field, and a image field etc and be able to do something with that. Maybe this is not the way it works Linux, maybe it a split something. Maybe there coding software, is split from GUI designing software.

So how do Linux developers normally do this?

Comment: this is open ended.  kdevelop is the closest to visual studio.  also, qt comes with its ui editor that you can use.

Comment: @thang kdevelop itself cannt biuld buttons etc, so then i wonder why you find it more closely looking liky VSstudio, i have yet to determine my tools write code, i was thinking of codeblocks.. but its a bit confusing for me. I am student level programmer.

Comment: kdevelop takes the qt editor as a plugin, so it can do ui editing.  you just need to get all the plugins.. there are several different ui editing plugins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A large number of developers and studios use [Qt](http://qt.digia.com) for Linux and Windows development. I highly recommend it as it provides you with an IDE called "QtCreator" and a designer, called "Designer" for laying out your forms and widgets.

Comment: Just a side note, as (s)he got some exp from MS. Even with the good quality of thoses tools, the learning curve is slower than visual studio. I'm still a QT fan tho!

Comment: And can QT be bound to something to write code with, your favorite code editor so one could use c++ or pyhon ? And as a visual studio-user is it possible to quickly make adjustments to the gui try the code and go on, or should i reserve a few hours for design export and some how call/import/ ore refer to it and try the code with it ?

Comment: @user613326 Generally, I have visual studios open along with Qt Designer, I modify my layout in Designer, save it, then click build in visual studio. The Qt plug-in detects the change in the ui file and the change is incorporated. It's that quick.

Comment: Ok i try it, it seams codeblocks has support for QT4 .. so i installed it but now i scratch my head where did it instal on linux.
While in windows i would look under program files, its not so clear for me on linux...hmm..puzzling

Comment: @user613326 on windows Qt generally installs under C:\Qt\{Version} while on linux, I think look under /usr/local by default

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned earlier qt and qt creator/designer are great for GUI applications. Another option would be to use GTK and Glade. Glade allows you to layout components in a wysiwyg editor and generates an xml files for the gui. Then using GTK you can load the xml file in your application using Gtk::Builder which will create the gui for you. Then you can get get pointers to the various components in the gui to add handler etc.

Comment: aha so multiple options for GUI design, i am new to a separate approach. i am interested in why you might prefer GTK and Glade vs QT
As a side note, my apps wont have many submenus or popups, so some simple easy GUI i would prefer above fancy looking things

Comment: The more popular desktop environments such as gnome are based on gtk and therefore gtk integrates well with these environments. Ubuntu and Mint both use gnome forks and therefore gtk integrates nicely with them. qt is the base of KDE, another popular desktop environment. qt is much more portable than gtk and can move to almost any other platform including mobile environments such as iOS and Android. qt does however give a slightly different look and feel compared to gtk. If you are going to be developing solely for mint gtk is probably the better option as it will have a better look and feel.